# Dealing with multiple special opcodes

Tags: c++

So I've been working on making a disassembler for Rockstar's scripting engine, and I'm currently dealing with adding all of the opcodes. To give a bit of background, each opcode is a string of bytes, with the first byte being the identifier to which opcode it is, followed by the data that opcode needs. The main problem I'm running into is that there are over 150 opcodes, all with different lengths and all needing different operations done to the following bytes to extract the correct data from them. So I'm mainly just asking for some other peoples opinions, but what would be the best way to handle all 150+ opcodes uniquely? I know I could use a big switch statement, but it would end up being extremely long, and I was thinking there must be a "cleaner" way to do it, I just can't think of one. If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A switch is normal. For a real world example, have a look at the Lua source, in particular lvm.c

Comment: I also believe a switch statement is normal in a procedural language. But, and I have never used it, I saw this cool library https://github.com/mpark/patterns (C++17). It essentially tries to provide some pattern matching functionality of functional languages like OCaml, Haskell, F# for C++.  Many parsers are written in functional languages because of there pattern matching abilities.

Comment: You can abstract your stuff into a table, where you look up the op code to get the entry describing how that's processed.  It might just have a function pointer, or maybe you have a small set of actual parameter formats and you can specify which one it uses and call a handler.  In C++, you also have polymorphism which is basically doing this for you.  Very hard to advise beyond generics when you don't show any code or specification of the problem.

Comment: When I did something similar I prepared a large Excel table. (Excel was convenient due to auto-complete etc. I saved the table as a tab-separated file.) Then I made an AWK code to translate that into C++ code fragments, a header with an enum, a header with little helper structs, and even the code for the disassembler. Of course, you could use Python instead of AWK, or anything else where you are able to master text processing in... If you are enthusiastic, you even can embed the compiling of the Excel table to C++ code into your build scripts (as I did). ;-)

Comment: Concerning the `switch`: I compared the `switch` orgy with an alternative approach where every opcode has it's own struct with a virtual member `exec()`. Due to my measurement, the `switch` was significantly faster (although I liked the virtual member approach more). I must admit that I did this measurement at least 10 years ago and never repeated it. A third approach might be a single function table (where opcodes are used as index into) but I didn't test it as I expected it close to the virtual member function approach. (I'm not fully sure about this anymore...)

Comment: The modern way would be to train a neural network with all the opcodes and some sample parameter data. If done right, most of the time it would give a sensible result.

Comment: [Rockstar's scripting engine](https://codewithrockstar.com/)?

Comment: https://youtu.be/IAdLwUXRUvg?t=1877

Comment: @MarekR no not that language haha I meant Rockstar Games internal scripting engine for games like GTA and Red Dead Redemption. Sorry should have been more clear

Comment: @Condor yest this comment was a joke. I like story [how this language was crated](https://youtu.be/6avJHaC3C2U?t=2799).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need performance, I would go with the hardcoded table.

If design is a big concerned and you can accept some performance lost, you could use the strategy design pattern. For example:

```cpp
class IOpcodeHandlingStrategy
{
public:

    virtual ~IOpcodeHandlingStrategy() = default;

    // Override this for every opcode, to handle it as it needs.
    virtual void Handle() = 0;
};
```

Then, you implement the interface for each opcode:

```cpp
class OpcodeAHandlingStrategy : public IOpcodeHandlingStrategy
{
public:

    OpcodeAHandlingStrategy(const std::string& opcode_)
    : m_opcode{opcode_}
    {}

    void Handle() override
    {
        // Use m_opcode and handle it here, for this concrete
        // opcode...
    }

private:

    std::string m_opcode;
};
```

With this, the switch statement can be moved inside a factory function, which would only be responsible in creating the right strategy and returning it (using the first byte). Something like:

```cpp
// ...
const std::string someOpcode = GetOpcode();
std::unique_ptr<IOpcodeHandlingStrategy> handlingStrategy = CreateOpcodeHandlingStrategy(someOpcode);
handlingStrategy->Handle();
// ...
```

What is neat about this solution is that the strategy interface and the factory method completely hide away the details of how opcode are handled to the rest of your application. If you need to change it later, the impact on the rest of the code would be minimal (only the factory and the strategies would be affected, which is where the responsibility lies). This also opens the door to unit testing.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for! Just want to make sure I'm not missing something, but is CreateOpcodeHandlingStrategy a method that returns the right strategy and you missed the "=" after handlingStrategy? Or is it something I'm unaware of? I'm still fairly new to C++ so I just wanted to know if that was something I haven't learned yet. Thanks again!

Comment: You are right, I updated the code! This kind of method is called a factory method, and it is responsible to create the right strategy based of the opcode.

Comment: Got it thanks! Got me going down the rabbit hole of self registering factories now haha